# Change default HDMI mode of monitor output

Tags: hdmi, display

I'm currently trying to set up my Raspberry Pi with ArchLinuxARM. Everything went fine so far but the display has a horribly low resolution, 640x480!
I'm using a HDMI to VGA converter box and an Acer monitor that normally can do a resolution of 1920x1080 @ 60 Hz. 
I know this is something that is widely discussed but I already did tons of google research and tried a lot but nothing seems to change anything.
My current `/boot/config.txt`, but I've already tried many different combinations:

```
hdmi_safe=1
disable_overscan=1
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=16
hdmi_drive=2
config_hdmi_boost=4
sdtv_mode=2
sdtv_aspect=1
hdmi_edid_file=1
## ... and overclocking settings on Turbo, but rather as a test
```

Also:

```
$ /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -s
state 0x12001a [HDMI DMT (4) RGB full 4:3], 640x480 @ 60.00Hz, progressive

$ /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -m CEA
mode 4: 1289x720 @ 60Hz 16:9, clock:74MHz progressive
mode 16: 1920x1080 @ 60Hz 16:9, clock:148MHz progressive

$ /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -m DMT
mode 4: 640x480 @ 60Hz 4:3, clock:25MHZ progressive
```

When I change `framebuffer_width` and `framebuffer_height` to something higher, the text gets smaller but also blurry, like theres no change in resolution but just in font size. I have black bars of about 10% at top, bottom, left and right of the screen, that don't change by changing the `overscan` attributes in the config.txt, neither with positive nor negative values. 
I can login via SSH and change the HDMI mode to CEA 16 DVI with

```
$ /opt/vc/bin/tvservice --explicit="CEA 16 DVI"
```

And the output of `tvservice -s` tells me that the mode is now the status but the monitor of the pi just turns black (different shades of black, depending on what hdmi mode I try) and stays that way. When I change the HDMI mode to 16, and reboot, the messages that appear on the screen actually have the right resolution but it reboots into HDMI mode 4 CEA again. 
I've already tried commenting out `disable_overscan`, using the `overscan` values, using different HDMI modes (1,4,16,31,32,47,68,69,71,71,72,73 with hdmi_group=2 and 1,4,16 with hdmi_group=1), using /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -d and enable `hdmi_edid_file=1`, changing sdtv_aspect and choosing different overclocking settings, and now I have the feeling I'm just looking at the wrong place...

I have already set up the raspberry pi with the same setting (at least I thought it would be the same) and the resolution was fine. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

I hope you can help me!

Comment: Are you sure your HDMI->VGA adapter supports 1920x1080? Could you perhaps post a link to the actual adapter you have in your possession?

Comment: FWIW - I use an HDMI->VGA adapter which works fine in 1920x1080 without needing to make any config.txt modifications - here is the link to the one I use: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00G9UWP94 .

Comment: I can't remember which one I bought, but also over amazon and it was a bit cheaper, about 5 Euro. I am sure that my adapter supports it because when I switched the hdmi mode over tvservice and then rebooted I could see the right resolution but only the shutdown messages. But before that the screen was blanking, so I was not able to use any terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, it works now. It seems to be the solution was to comment out `hdmi_safe=1`. I tried to disable everything that does not change anything and ended up with this `/boot/config.txt`:

```
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=47
hdmi_drive=2
```

Thanks to everyone who helped!

Comment: do you mean *comment out* `hdmi_safe=1` or uncomment it? I don't see `hdmi_safe=1` in the full config you listed.

Comment: I commented it out. In the file listed in the question it was uncommented. The file that is listed in the answer is everything that was needed. I didn't write down explicitly which options were also in the file, that I commented out.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to `config.txt` :

`hdmi_force_hotplug=1`

Comment: Tried it - doesn't change anything...